# Redirection in envoy

Tags: docker, envoyproxy

I'm testing an envoy configuration in my stage environment, here I need to make a redirection to custom page "/oops", whenever there occurs any 5xx error while calling test.com. It is accessible the path "http://test1.com/oops" directly. Can anybody please suggest me ideas?

```
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - name: test-listener
    address:
      socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 30000 }

    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.http_connection_manager
        config:
          access_log:
            - name: envoy.file_access_log
              config:
                path: "/dev/stdout"
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: local_service
              domains: ["test1.com"]
              routes:
              - match: { prefix: "/" }
                route: { cluster: test1_service }
            - name: local_service2
              domains: ["test2.com"]
              routes:
              - match: { prefix: "/" }
                route: { cluster: google_service }

          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.router

  clusters:
  - name: test1_service
    connect_timeout: 0.25s
    type: LOGICAL_DNS
    dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
    lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
    hosts: [{ socket_address: { address: 172.17.0.3, port_value: 80 }}]

  - name: google_service
    connect_timeout: 0.25s
    type: LOGICAL_DNS
    dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
    lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
    hosts: [{ socket_address: { address: google.com, port_value: 80 }}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HTTP Routing](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/intro/arch_overview/http/http_routing#arch-overview-http-routing) in envoy to accomplish this. Also refer the [route.VirtualHost](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v2/api/v2/route/route.proto#route-virtualhost) config.